# How json animation of Shape.so animated illustrator

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, animation, jquery-animate

i'm using Shape.so animated illustrator on html page they are providing json code for that can anyone help how to use that json in html.

I have json file, you can export json from https://shape.so/app/icons/

thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by using `json` in `html`?

Comment: i want to animated that json file in HTML? can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can import Lottie and use loadAnimation method as described here:

https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/web?id=usage

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #anim {
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="anim"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.7.4/lottie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var element = document.getElementById('anim');
        lottie.loadAnimation({
            container: element, // the dom element that will contain the animation
            renderer: 'svg',
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            path: 'data.json' // the path to the animation json
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```